# Is it possible to select comments in xhtml with php?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Here is the code that i am trying to implement

$selector = xpath select for comments

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
foreach ($xpath->query($selector) as $aNode) 
{ 
echo ($aNode->nodeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are selected by

```
//comment()
```

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm! Can you point me to an online resource documenting all xpath selectors?

Answer (score 0):

[Simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is like jQuery, but in PHP ... I think that's what you want. MIT License ;)

Comment: I know simplehtmldom can do it. but it has severe limitations, for which reason i had to give it up.

Comment: What is the limitation of the server?

Comment: No server limitation. simplehtmldom sometimes fails to select elements, and gives weird results even with well formed xhtml. I learnt this the hard way, so had to abandon it.

Comment: @Alfonso: "severe" != "server" ;)